# ursina loads frameanimation3d in the wrong order

Tags: python-3.x, animation, ursina

so this is the code loading the anim
`

```
hand = FrameAnimation3d('assets\playerhand\hanim2\\cube_',
                        position=(5, 2, 5),
                        scale = 0.1,
                        loop = False,
                        autoplay = False,
                        fps = 100,

                )
```

`

and this is how it loads

read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_1.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_10.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_11.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_12.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_13.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_14.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_15.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_16.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_17.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_18.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_19.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_2.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_20.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_21.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_22.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_23.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_24.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_25.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_26.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_27.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_28.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_29.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_3.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_30.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_31.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_32.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_33.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_34.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_35.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_36.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_37.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_38.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_39.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_4.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_40.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_41.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_42.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_43.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_44.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_45.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_46.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_47.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_48.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_49.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_5.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_50.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_51.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_52.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_53.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_54.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_55.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_56.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_57.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_58.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_59.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_6.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_60.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_61.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_62.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_63.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_64.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_65.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_66.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_67.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_68.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_69.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_7.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_70.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_71.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_72.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_73.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_74.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_75.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_76.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_77.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_78.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_79.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_8.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_80.obj
read obj at: C:\Users\l0g1c0n\PycharmProjects\game\assets\playerhand\hanim2\cube_9.obj

Answer (score 0):

ok so i actually got some kind of answer which is to delete first single digit frames but its not that good because u have to delete them
but  it loads nice so ye

Answer (score 0):

It loads them alphabetically. Usually exporters will add `0`s before the extentions so they're all the same length, like: cube_0001.obj, cube_0002.obj, cube_0003.obj, and so on.